# Выбор папки в QFileDialog

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qfiledialog

Есть задача чтобы при выборе `file_dialog` возвращала выбранную папку работает некорректно. Ниже код

```
# Выбор файла, работает корректно
    def get_file_dbf():
        if ui.file_dialog.exec_():
            file_name = ui.file_dialog.selectedFiles()
            if file_name[0].endswith('.py'):
                with open(file_name[0], 'r') as f:
                    ui.lineEdit.setText(file_name[0])
                    f.close()
            else:
                pass
#Выбор папки работает некорректно
    def select_folder_to_save():
        if ui.file_dialog_2.exec_():
            dirlist = ui.file_dialog_2.getExistingDirectory()
            ui.lineEdit_2.setText(dirlist)
    
#Вызов при нажатии на кнопки 
    ui.toolButton.clicked.connect(get_file_dbf);
    ui.toolButton_2.clicked.connect(select_folder_to_save);
```

Первая функция возвращает файл, в этом проблем нету, возвращает пути выбранного файла. а вот вторая работает следующим образом

1. Нажимаю на кнопку открывается диалоговое окно выбрать файл
2. Выбираю файл, окно закрывается и тут же открывается окно для выбора папки
3. Выбираю папку, путь сохраняется а приложение сворачивается.

Почему открывается сначала окно для выбора файл а потом сразу же папки, хотя делаю только по папке? И сворачивается приложение, непонятно почему

Ссылка на проект
https://repl.it/repls/MisguidedClutteredRevisioncontrol

Comment: Опубликуйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: в каком формате вам опубликовать? немного не понял просто @S.Nick

Comment: вы публикуете вопрос и описываете проблему, при этом приводите отрывок кода. Если вам действительно нужна помощь вы должны предоставить пример, который можно скопировать, запустить и получить проблему, о которой вы пишите. Поэтому я не понимаю ваш дополнительный вопрос: `в каком формате вам опубликовать?`

Comment: @S.Nick Загрузил вот сюда https://repl.it/repls/MisguidedClutteredRevisioncontrol Сорри немного затуил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я не проверял логику программы в целом.

Отвечаю на вопрос: `Почему открывается сначало окно для выбора файл а потом сразу же папки, хотя делаю только по папке?`

Функция `select_folder_to_save` должна выглядеть так:

```
def select_folder_to_save():
#    if ui.file_dialog_2.exec_():
    dirlist = ui.file_dialog_2.getExistingDirectory()
    if dirlist:
        ui.lineEdit_2.setText(dirlist)
```

Также НЕ рекомендую вам изменять модуль созданный в `Qt Designer` - НИКОГДА.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]